# parse xml into UITableView

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, uitableview

I have an XML file on my server and I need to parse it into my iOS app and then I need to put it into a `UITableView`. My XML looks like this:

```
<plan>
    <action>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>item 1</name>
    </action>
    <action>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>item 2</name>
    </action>
    <action>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>item 3</name>
    </action>
</plan>
```

I need to fetch every instance of that `<item>` tag into the table view.

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta use NSXMLParser to parse your XML file see [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/). Or try [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fiphonedevsdk.com%2Fforum%2Fiphone-sdk-development%2F40819-parsing-an-xml-using-nsxmlparser.html&ei=EsRuUYqPF47krAeHr4CgCw&usg=AFQjCNG6RSzC8fVvv8IOzLVzSQYTp8Spcg&sig2=4v1H-K0F8xagZMhMflC4qQ&bvm=bv.45368065,d.bmk).

Answer (score 2):

Apple has provided an example which may contains exactly what you need, the project is called LazyTableImages and you can find it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394)

This example will do perform the following steps:

1. Parse content with NSXMLParser by calling its delegate methods
2. Load parsed data into ViewController
3. Reload UITableView data to display contents extracted from XML

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
#import <Foundation/
Foundation.h>

@interface Parser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableString *element;
    NSString *tag;
}

@end
//initalization of parser
-init {
   if(self == [super init]) {
          //pass in your xml file/code here here.
          parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]
initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType: @"xml"]]];
          [parser setDelegate:self];
          [parser parse];
   }      
   return self;
}
//start parsing
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary
*)attributeDict {

NSLog(@"Started
Element %@", elementName);
      element = [NSMutableString
string];

}

// end parsing
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

      if([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]
        tag = element;

}

save the string
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 

 if(element == nil)
   element = [[NSMutableString
alloc] init];
   [element appendString:string];
}
```

Hope this helps...